# intellij idea run configurations backup

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to create a script to modify my debug configuration in intellij. The path of tomcat changes, and i have to manually go into the run config and edit things. I have tried to find the place where intellij stores these settings to no avail.

**question**: does anyone know where IJ stores its run configuration

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The location would depend on 2 factors, whether the configuration is local to the user or shared with the other developers and if you are using the file based (legacy) or the directory based project format.

- File based project, local configuration: `.iws` file
- Directory based project, local configuration: `workspace.xml` file under `.idea` directory
- File based project, shared configuration: `.ipr` file
- Directory based project, shared configuration: `.xml` file under `runConfigurations` subdirectory of `.idea` directory or files inside `.run` directory in the project root (you can customize the location of the shared configurations in the latest versions).

Comment: +1, useful! I currently have my Tomcat configs in .idea/workspace.xml - any idea how I could easily switch to having them under runConfigurations (for easier sharing)?

Comment: Use `Share configuration` checkbox in the Run/Debug configuration settings.

Comment: `.xml` file sunder `runConfigurations` are awesome but for some reason IDEA keeps changing them frequently (just reorders the list of environment variables for instance).

Comment: Clicking "Share" and then "Apply" didn't do the trick for me. I had to exit out of the Run/Debug Configurations screen in intellij before the `runConfigurations` directory appeared.

Comment: For new versions of IntelliJ, the "share" option is replaced with "store as project file". Compare this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64263851/2792414

Answer (score 31):

Its here .idea\runConfigurations (correct for Idea 11). Just copy this folder to new project.

EDIT: As per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135834/intellij-idea-run-configurations-backup?answertab=oldest#comment7875514_3136255), if runConfigurations folder doesn't exist, check the 'Share' box inside the Run/Debug configuration