# Store android run/debug configuration IntelliJ idea and svn

Tags: android, svn, intellij-idea

I'm recently started working on a school project using IntelliJ IDEA to develop an Android app.  Most of the guys in my team (me included) are used to the way visual studio organizes project into .sln files.  We've had all sorts of frustrations with IntelliJ mostly because we don't understand how IntelliJ organizes projects.  We finally got the project to load reliably without having to make changes to each developers set up by following the steps here: 
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1186.  However, now anytime we get latest the Run/Debug configurations disappear.  Anyone having the same problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136255/104891).

Make sure that you are sharing your configurations and files from the `.idea/runConfigurations` directory are added to the version control.