# Share checkbox in Run/Debug Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

What is the purpose of "Share" checkbox in the Run/Debug Configuration screen?

[image]

I thought it's a way to share this configuration between projects, but when I open a new project, I cannot find this config in a list of predefined configurations or similar list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This check box for sharing Run/Debug Configuration between team members. Check the **Share** option in this [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configurations.html) for more details. Also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136255/2650174).