# Reordering the deployment artifacts in Glassfish App Server in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I am running IntelliJ Idea 13.1 and I am not able to find a way to manually provide the order of deployment of EAR , WAR Artifacts using IntelliJ GlassFish Application Server support.

IntelliJ keeps order as MyAdmin.war, **MyEAR.ear**, MyWeb.war

I want to reorder it as **MyEAR.ear**, MyAdmin.war, MyWeb.war (EAR before WARs)

But in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 I am unable to find any option to do so.
GlassFish I am using is 3.1.2

See attached screenshot for understanding the deployment issue.

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the order matter?

Comment: In our application, the Ear needs to be deployed first as the wars have deployment dependency on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the description of the start configuration in .idea/workspace.xml (see [intellij idea run configurations backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135834/intellij-idea-run-configurations-backup))

```
<configuration name="StartConf" ...
<deployment>
<artifact name="1" />
<artifact name="2" />
```

Here you can set the order as you needed.

Comment: Thanks @ntodorov70, I could find the following in Idea **workspace.xml** and changed it accordingly
`<deployment>
        <artifact name="MyEar:ear">
          <settings />
        </artifact>
        <artifact name="MyWeb:war">
          <settings />
        </artifact>
        <artifact name="MyAdmin:war">
          <settings />
        </artifact>
      </deployment>`
and when I saved and reloaded the project as prompted by Idea, I could see changed order in Glassfish app server.

Comment: Though the hack provided by @ntodorov70 works but whenever I open or edit the configuration in IntelliJ Idea, it again reverts to artifact names in alphabetical order. I think IntelliJ Idea Team must provide artifact re-ordering option in UI.