# Where are IDEA run/debug configuration *defaults* stored?

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration

It's easy to [share run configurations *instances* in IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10834073/96588) - simply instantiate a configuration and check "Share":
[image: Run/Debug Configurations dialog]

I'm already version controlling the resulting files in `.idea/runConfigurations` (in the relevant project) and part of `~/.IntelliJIdea*` (for puppetising desktops). However, I can't find **where IDEA stores the configuration *defaults*** - it doesn't seem to be in either of these places. They must obviously be persisting it *somewhere*, because it works across restarts. The [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/create-run-debug-configuration-for-gradle-tasks.html) is unusually unhelpful in this case:

> This check box is not available when editing the run/debug configuration defaults.

The particular use case is that I'd like all future "Behave" configurations to have the environment variable `DISPLAY` set to `:1` to run browser tests in VNC rather than in the foreground.

Comment: Defaults (the ones that you configure under `Defaults` node from your screenshot) are stored together with other non-shared configs in `.idea/workspace.xml` -- look for `<component name="RunManager"` node. Obviously, they are per-project settings so every project will have its own defaults.

Comment: @LazyOne That's correct (and the last place I'd expect them to save *defaults*)! Do you mind adding that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Defaults (the ones that you configure under Defaults node from your screenshot) are per-project .. and therefore stored together with other non-shared configs in `.idea/workspace.xml` (which is not supposed to be stored under VCS as it contains developer/computer specific settings).
2. You can find such entries in the aforementioned file under `<component name="RunManager"` node. Default entries will have `default="true"` attribute.
3. There is no defaults of defaults for run/debug configs that you can edit/provision (configs that would be applied to any new projects). They are not stored in separate config file(s) on IDE level but initiated directly from plugin code .