# InlliJ CLI Misconfigiuration Upon Opening

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration

I have the following version of IntelliJ:
[image: IntelliJ Version]

Ant taking this other image into account:
[image: Grails Project Configuration]

The problem is that, every time I turn on the computer and wants to open de IDE or every time I close and open, the "Command Line" and "VM Options" are emptied... How could I solve this ?...

Comment: You may want to try the latest version of IntelliJ and see if the issue persists or open an issue on the IntelliJ bug tracker. Lastly you can try to use the gradle bootRun task instead of the grails run-app.

Comment: Update to the latest version, see if the parameters are really saved: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3136255/104891.