# Tomcat/IntelliJ disconnect

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, http-status-code-404

I'd like recommendations on what low hanging fruit to look for in this scenario.  I'm hoping it's a basic setup thing that will be answered without burdening everyone with too much detail.  I had a functioning web service running in IntelliJ/Tomcat, but my workstation died.  On the new computer I imported the (maven) project from our git repository, installed Tomcat, and fired everything up - no code errors, no errors in Tomcat starting up - but I now get 404 Errors consistently when I try to access the web service.  Any initial thoughts on perhaps an IntelliJ configuration item I'm missing that would not have come along with the project import?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3136255/104891. Since you now have the new project, you no longer have your previous run/debug configurations which probably specified a different URL and a different deployment context for Tomcat. Most likely, you are either opening another URL now or the app is being deployed under a different context.

Comment: Thanks so much - you hit the nail on the head.  I didn't have any artifacts set up in the run definition.  I was dearly hoping it was something like that!  Now if I can just figure out how to mark this as answered and give you appropriate credit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have an artifact associated with my run/debug configuration.  Added the artifact and things took off.  Thanks to [CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder) for the suggestion.