# How to export by IntelliJ the run configuration e.g. maven configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, intellij-14

I'm looking in IntelliJ for something like launcher by Eclipse?

However, is it possible to export the configuration in IntelliJ to file.

[image]

I would like to add the configuration to repo, to share it for the team.

Comment: [This official JetBrain blog post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206905825-how-to-persist-and-import-run-configurations) seems to either answer your question of be a good starting point.  Try searching the documentation and I think you will already find a solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136255/104891.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create and edit script launcher over Run/Debug Configuration - (1)

Check the share option (2),

so the script will be stored under $projectDir/.idea/runConfigurations (3)

By new projects modify `.gitignore` to add the configurations:

```
!.idea
.idea/*
!.idea/runConfigurations
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by pressing the "Share" checkbox in the upper right corner inside 
 the "Run/debug configurations". A file with configurations will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

well, that requires vcs and that repo has been closed. i need to move them from the closed repo to the new one.