# Intellij not showing submodules of multi module maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

My pom.xml that has been stable for over 24 months is now not working within Intellij - and I can not figure out why it stopped doing so. Here is the `modules` section:

```
<modules>
    <module>tcpclient</module>
    <module>tfdma</module>
    <module>tf</module>
    <module>tfspark</module>
    <module>registry</module>
    <module>p2prdd</module>
</modules>
```

But now the already-existing `Run Configurations` are no longer working due to not finding classes. I can not even *see* the modules to try to fix the problem :note that only the *Parent* module is shown

[image]

Note that my next step will be to blow away all the `Intellij` artifacts such `*.iml` and `.idea/*` . But there is a *cost* to that: e.g. losing my (intricate) run configurations. This is not a preferred solution.

Any ideas why this would have happened?

Comment: Try reimporting, you can backup and restore your run configurations per https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136255/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder hey thanks for stopping by - always great to get _the_ IJ guy here!. Thx for the `runConfigurations` tip. See my answer also below: the workaround is pretty light-hearted/relatively painless.    I'm just _lost_ without IJ (nothing else comes remotely close to its power) so whatever little kinks come up we just do what we can.

Comment: Give this a try.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6jirc1x25U

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to pom.xml of each module, right click -> add as maven project.
This should solve the issue.

Version:2020.2.2

Comment: I'll assume this has now been fixed and your answer were correct.

Comment: I have added my intellij version.

Comment: This works, thanks! But ... why do I have to do this, why is this not done automatically?

Comment: No idea, somehow I keep getting this issue and this is the only remedy.

Answer (score 9):

Just check if the pom of submodule is not ignored (strike out) Right click on submodule's pom.xml -> maven -> unignore projects

Comment: This answer helped me fixing the issue; I had to right-click on the pom and actually ignore each maven submodule first. After doing that, you can unignore the modules again. Only then IntelliJ would recognize it again as a maven module.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did an ignore then unignore on one submodule and they all got recognised.

Answer (score 1):

I walked into a workaround: do `Import Module from [Maven] Model` under `Project Structure`:

[image]

After pointing to *one* of the half dozen modules and clicking `OK` then Intellij re-imported *all six*  for me:

[image]

So this is  bit weird but then not so bad to resolve..

Comment: [This bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211346) might be the case. It's fixed in https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/. The workaround in the ticket looks similar to what you did.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thx for that info! Always great when you have a chance to stop by.

Answer (score 1):

I know that question is a little older, but I had the same problem again today and might save others some time.

The setup was working nicely and all of a sudden it stopped working in IDEA (but was still working with Maven on command line). Classes from module B were not found in module A anymore, class search didn't work etc. After trying everything else and re-importing module B, submodules B1, B2, ... were not recognized as Maven modules anymore.

What helped in the end was right-clicking on Module B ⇒ Load/Unload modules ⇒ selecting all submodules ⇒ load and a "Reload all Maven project" from Maven tab afterward. Now, everything is fine again. Just took me a couple of hours to get it running...

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Selecting all projects then unignore and reload was the right sequence for me.